# preg_replace PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace

i have an annoying problem with `preg_replace` and charsets. I'm doing a couple `preg_replace` in a row but unfortunate the first time any special character like `äöüß` is inserted by preg_replace i'm getting `PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR` on subsequent calls.

Beside that the special characters inserted are displayed just fine, they just break any subsequent `preg_replace` call. Is preg_ utf-8 only?

The text `preg_replace` is working on is coming from MySQL Database, also the replacement is crafted in the php file with values from MySQL. `mb_detect_encoding()` says `ASCII` for the text until the first replacement with special characters, it then detects `UTF-8`, so it changes and this might be the problem.

For your information i'm working with iso-8859-1 encoding (PHP, MySQL, meta-charset). Furthermore i have a workaround with htmlentities on the replacement string that is working for now.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php). It handles multibyte encodings and should perform fine with differrent ones. Be sure to use [mb_regex_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) along with it.