# Fixing preg_replace PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace

I've read this - [preg_replace PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103692/preg-replace-preg-bad-utf8-error) but the answer didn't really help me. I want to remove some of the unprintable characters from string. This is my code:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
$string = "Cortège\x99 de gymnastique devant LL. MM. ęźżąśł";

echo mb_detect_encoding($string);
var_dump(mb_ereg_replace("/\\x99/u", '', $string));
var_dump(preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR);
```

Things I want to remove are for example "\x99". Output from given code is:

> UTF-8
>
> string 'CortĂ¨ge de gymnastique devant LL. MM. ÄĹşĹźÄĹĹ'
>   (length=52)
>
> boolean true

How am I supposed to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use delimiters in mb_ereg_replace

when i use

```
echo 'encoding ' . mb_detect_encoding($string) . "\n\n<br/>";
echo 'replace result ' . mb_ereg_replace("\\x99", '', $string) . "\n\n<br/>";
```

I get

```
encoding UTF-8 
replace result Cortège de gymnastique devant LL. MM. ęźżąśł
```

\x99 is gone